# Git Interactive Rebase - Order of commits and which to pick/squash

Tags: git

Let's say I have the following:

```
pick b0bc3ea Issue #1431 - Part 1
pick 606e9bc Issue #1431 - Part 2
```

Part 2 is obviously the most recent commit. Does it matter which way I squash it? Do I need to squash older into newer, newer into older, or does it matter?

Thanks!

Comment: The [`git rebase` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode) has a section on this topic and more.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To combine those two commits, use the following:

```
pick b0bc3ea Issue #1431 - Part 1
s 606e9bc Issue #1431 - Part 2
```

The rebase file is processed in order, and the `s` command squashes that commit into the previous commit (and gives you an opportunity to edit the commit message).

If you tried to make the first commit `s`, then it would try to squash that into the commit *before* that one. If you changed the order and picked Part 2 first and tried to squash Part 1 into that, you would probably get merge conflicts.

Comment: So in other wards, the highest entry in the interactive rebase dialog should always be a pick?

Comment: If by "highest" you mean "the one at the top of the file", then yes, most of the time. But you could certainly change it to something else, like `e` if you wanted to edit the first commit.

Comment: Ok that makes tons of sense, but I wasn't really reading that clearly anywhere. Thanks so much.